# Why does the dynamicallly created spinner not close on select

Tags: android, spinner

I create a spinner dynamically (within an alert).

If I Select a spinner item a new `Activity` gets started, some inputs will done and after the Activity ends with `finish()` and the last `Activtiy` is still open and the spinner is still there. Why it doesn't get closed onSelect? I don't need it open anymore -> the selection is done....

How I get it closed?

Comment: you are not clear, either clear yourself or show your code

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close it manually. Try to attach an `OnItemSelectedListener` like this:

```
public MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to read this :)